# ns-3 build finishing successfully but program not running

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ns-3

When I am running the command

```sh
./waf --run hello-simulator

Waf: Entering directory `/home/n/build'
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/n/build'
Build commands will be stored in build/compile_commands.json
'build' finished successfully (6.072s)
```

Build is finishing successfully but no output of the program showing.

Comment: You should check if the log component is enabled in the hello-simulator program.

Comment: I just checked in hello-simulator program,  NS_LOG_UNCOND ("Hello Simulator");  is already defined

Comment: No I meant if you have `NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE` for your program and then if you've subsequently enabled the component by `LogComponentEnable`.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, turns out my `waf` was not properly configured. so try the below commands to configure it again. (reason for this maybe sudden interruption or just wrong sequence of configuration)

**configuring waf**

```
cd ns-3.32 (your version might be different)
  CXXFLAGS="-O3" ./waf configure
  ./waf -d optimised configure; ./waf
  ./waf --disable-python configure
  ./waf --enable-sudo configure
  ./waf distclean
  rm -rf build
  ./build.py
```